# Select(expression) After Where() clause in repository pattern .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

New to .net core and I'm using Onion architecture to build my application. I have some methods to get data, but I want to implement some particular ways to get data from DB.

`IRepositoryBase`:

```cs
IQueryable<T> GetRelationData(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool trackChanges);
```

`RepositoryBase`:

```cs
public IQueryable<T> GetRelationData(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool trackChanges)
{
    return trackChanges ? RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression) 
                        : RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).Select(expression);
}
```

I'm getting this error when I implement the above method as shown:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

The below code is from.net Entity framework and it's working.

```
var parkRate = await _db.Parks.Where(x => x.OutTime == null && x.RateId == rateType.Id).Select(x => x.RateId).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why would you want to pass the where condition to Select? Select changes the return type to whatever the expression returns. Your expression returns a `bool`, but your method definition returns `T` which are not the same type

Comment: `var parkRate = await _db.Parks.Where(x => x.OutTime == null && x.RateId == rateType.Id).Select(x => x.RateId).ToListAsync();`

This is what I try to do,

The above code is a .Net, Entity framework. (Not core) and it's working.

Comment: well you would need to pass another separate expression for `.Select()`. As you can see you want to pass different expressions to `.Where` and to `.Select()`, but you what you do is pass the same one. Even though, it would not fix the problem, because you return `IQueryable<T>`, but your Select expression will probably return some different type like `int` or `string`, but not `T`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like this:

```cs
public IQueryable<T> GetRelationData(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, bool trackChanges)
{
    var query = RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(filter);
    if (!trackChanges)
        query = query.AsNoTracking();
    return query;
}
```